# Long form of acronyms capitalized in section headings

Tags: sectioning, formatting, glossaries, capitalization

I use the `glossaries` package and defined headers often in section titles.

In general I keep the first letter of each word in the headings in capital case, but if an acronym occurs the first time, it is printed in full length, but I can only capitalize the first letter by command.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{test}{TTSbCiH}{this text should be capitalized in headings}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\section{\Gls{test}}
\Glsfirst{test}

\glsfirst{test}
\end{document}
```

which looks like

[image]

But, it should rather be "1 This Text Should Be Capitalized In Headings"
(even better was "1 This Text Should be Capitalized in Headings")

How can I achieve that?

Comment: To be honest, as it stands now, i would just not use the mechanism of glossaries and set the description by hand. If you want to do that multiple times (not just two or three), you *can* probably automate this, but the question that arises for me would be: Is a sectin heading really the right thing to use here?

Answer (score 3):

I would patch this setup by adding a macro `\Glsheading` that retrieves a capitalized version of the long acronym description. So, you could say something like

```
\section{\Glsheading{test}}
```

In the `glossaries` package those things are accomplished with token registers. For your purpose it will be sufficent to store the relevant information into a macro. Hence a definition of `\Glsheading` could look like

```
\newcommand{\Glsheading}[1]{\@nameuse{gls@cap@head@#1}}
```

Now, you need to include a little module to `\newacronym` that stores the control sequence `gls@cap@head@#1`, or in your example case `\gls@cap@head@test` (=> "This Text Should Be Capitalized In Headings (TTSbCiH)"):

```
\LetLtxMacro{\gls@newacronym}{\newacronym}
\renewcommand{\newacronym}[4][]{%
  \gls@newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}
  \@namedef{gls@cap@head@#2}{\capitalize{#4} (#3)}}
\newcommand{\Glsheading}[1]{\@nameuse{gls@cap@head@#1}}
```

<sub>Note: This definition uses the `letltxmacro` package and a helper macro `\capitalize` (given in the complete code)</sub>

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

%<begin_patch>
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\gls@newacronym}{\newacronym}
\renewcommand{\newacronym}[4][]{%
  \gls@newacronym[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}
  \@namedef{gls@cap@head@#2}{\capitalize{#4} (#3)}}
\newcommand{\Glsheading}[1]{\@nameuse{gls@cap@head@#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\capitalize}[1]{%
  \ignorespaces
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \xcapitalize\expandafter\space #1 \relax}
\def\xcapitalize#1 #2{%
  #1%
  \ifx\relax#2\else
    \space\MakeUppercase{#2}%
    \expandafter\xcapitalize
  \fi}
%<end_patch>

\newacronym{test}{TTSbCiH}{this text should be capitalized in headings}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\section{\Glsheading{test}}
\Glsfirst{test}\\
\glsfirst{test}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```